# Is there a way to implement generic function in C++ without the use of templates and without the use of void pointers?

Tags: c++, function, generics

I want to know that can we implement a function whose instance can be created for different data types during runtime but we are not allowed to use either templates or void pointers.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Short Answer: No.

Comment: You're asking to do a thing without the tools provides expressly for that same purpose. Describing your actual problem would be beneficial.

Comment: also templates alone do not let you create functions for different types at runtime

Comment: `std::any` to replace `void*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use a macro.

```
#define instantiate_generic_function(Type) \
void myGenericFunction(Type param) { \
    std::cout << param; \
}
```

and then instantiate like thus:

```
instantiate_generic_function(int)
```

This makes a series of overloaded functions named `myGenericFunction`

---

Another option that [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) reminded me that there's also function-like macros, which come with a different set of pros and cons.

```
#define myGenericFunction(var) do { \
    std::cout << (var); 
} while (false)
```

The `do{}while` allows you to use this as if it were a regular function after a one-line if  branch and other similar conditions

```
if (thing == true) 
    myGenericFunction(var);
```

Comment: or even function macro `#define print(var) do { std::cout << (var); } while (false)` and avoid type checking.

Comment: It is quite insightful.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the `std::any` type (since C++17) to *"implement a generic function"* (as your question's **title** states).

However, this won't allow *"a function whose instance can be created for different data types during runtime"* (as stated in the **body** of your question) – it will just be a single function that can (conditionally) handle different argument types.

Here's a short example:

```cpp
#include <any>
#include <typeindex>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void MultiFunc(std::any arg)
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    auto a = std::type_index(arg.type());
    std::string name{ a.name() };
    std::cout << "Called with argument of type: " << name << std::endl;
    // Conditional actions ...
    auto& t = arg.type();
    if (t == typeid(double)) {
        double dval = std::any_cast<double>(arg);
        std::cout << "Doubling the double argument gives: " << dval * 2;
    }
    else if (t == typeid(int)) {
        int ival = std::any_cast<int>(arg);
        std::cout << "Incrementing the int argument gives: " << ++ival;
    }
    else if (t == typeid(std::string)) {
        std::string sval = std::any_cast<std::string>(arg);
        std::reverse(sval.begin(), sval.end());
        std::cout << "Reversing the std::string argument gives: " << sval;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Hmmm ... not sure what to do with that type of argument!";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    double d = 2.1;
    int i = 41;
    std::string s = "!madA m'I ,madaM";
    MultiFunc(d);
    MultiFunc(i);
    MultiFunc(s);
    MultiFunc("Hello!");
    return 0;
}
```